# WPS process importing and returning output

Tags: geoserver, wps

I'd like to import to the GeoServer catalog the result of one of my processes (in addition to returning it to the client), which is a shapefile.
I have managed to find some kind of import code, but it doesn't publish the layer. I also have to return a URL that links to that newly imported shapefile.

My code so far : (I have simplified a little bit, I understand that the way it is presented here (with a direct path) is useless.)

```
@DescribeProcess(title = "AddSHP", description = "Returns a SHP")
public class AddSHP implements GSProcess {

private Catalog catalog;

public AddSHP(Catalog catalog) {
    this.catalog = catalog;
}

@DescribeResult(name="ShapeFile", description="ShapeFile", type = String.class)
public RETURN_TYPE execute(
        throws IOException {
    String shp;
    shp = "Path/to/my/shape.shp";
    String shpname = shp.substring(shp.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    addShapeFileDataStore(shpname, shpname, shp);
    return (SOMETHING);
}

private boolean addShapeFileDataStore(String title, String description, String pathToFile)  {
    DataStoreInfo dsInfo = catalog.getFactory().createDataStore();
    dsInfo.setName(title);
    dsInfo.setDescription(description);
    dsInfo.setEnabled(true);
    dsInfo.setType("Shapefile");
    dsInfo.getConnectionParameters().put("create spatial index", true);
    dsInfo.getConnectionParameters().put("charset", "ISO-8859-1");
    dsInfo.getConnectionParameters().put("filetype", "shapefile");
    dsInfo.getConnectionParameters().put("cache and reuse memory maps", true);
    dsInfo.getConnectionParameters().put("url", "file:" + pathToFile);
    dsInfo.getConnectionParameters().put("namespace", "http://");
    try {
        catalog.add(dsInfo);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("Error adding data store to catalog");
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Could anybody help ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have got what I wanted to import and publish a shapefile :

```
public class AddSHP implements GSProcess {

private Catalog catalog;

public AddSHP(Catalog catalog) {
    this.catalog = catalog;
}

@DescribeResult(name="ShapeFile", description="ShapeFile", type = String.class)
public String execute(
        @DescribeParameter(name = "Useless number", description = "Any random useless number") int i)
                throws IOException {
    String shp = "Path/to/my/shape.shp";
    String shpName = shp.substring(shp.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
    String shpExt = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(shpName);
    File zipShp = new File(FilenameUtils.removeExtension(shp)+".zip");

    try {
        if (zipShp.exists())
        {
            System.out.println("Removing existing zip file");
            zipShp.delete();
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipShp);
        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);

        File directory = new File(shp).getParentFile();
        for(File f : directory.listFiles())
        {
            if(f.getName().startsWith(shpExt) && !f.getName().endsWith(".zip"))
                addToZipFile(f, zos);
        }

        zos.close();
        fos.close();

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    GeoServerRESTPublisher gsrp = new GeoServerRESTPublisher("http://localhost:8080/geoserver", "admin", "meteorite");
    gsrp.removeDatastore("Map", shpExt, true);
    gsrp.publishShp("Map", shpExt, shpExt, zipShp);

    return ("Done !");
    }

public static void addToZipFile(File f, ZipOutputStream zos) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String fileName = f.getPath();
    System.out.println("Writing '" + fileName + "' to zip file");

    File file = new File(fileName);
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    ZipEntry zipEntry = new ZipEntry(f.getName());
    zos.putNextEntry(zipEntry);

    byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = fis.read(bytes)) >= 0) {
        zos.write(bytes, 0, length);
    }

    zos.closeEntry();
    fis.close();
}
}
```

As in the question, I do understand that this code seems useless, but it is a simplified version of a process aimed at importing shapefile data after it has been created by another process, and it's just the first step.